# AJAX Request when submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added to my form a special id which I would like to track. If this id is available in the form, an AJAX request should be initialised.

**Form**

```
        {!! Form::open(['data-remote', 'action' => 'IncidentsController@store', 'id'=>'incidentEntryForm']) !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('city', 'Name:') !!}
            {!! Form::text('city', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </div>
(...)
```

Therefore I wrote this helper script:

**Helper Script**

```
(function() {
    console.log("Helper OK");

    var submitAjaxRequest = function(e) {
        var form = $(this);
        var method = form.find('input[name="_method"]').val() || 'POST';

        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: form.prop('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function() {
                console.log("Submit OK");
                $.publish('form.submitted', form);
            }
        })
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    // forms marked with the "data-remote" attribute will submit, via AJAX.
    $('form[data-remote]').on('submit', submitAjaxRequest);
})();
```

The `$.publish` is a short script for PubSub Functionality I included as well.

**PubSub**

```
(function($) {
    console.log('PubSub OK');
    var o = $({});

    $.subscribe = function() {
        o.on.apply(o, arguments);
    };

    $.unsubscribe = function() {
        o.off.apply(o, arguments);
    };

    $.publish = function() {
        o.trigger.apply(o, arguments);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

But when I press the submit button, the last line of the helper script does not seem to react. The function submitAjaxRequest is never called.

The script is included in my head section. For checking if this is loaded, I included the console.log at the beginning. I see the output. So it is running I think. But it does not react to the submit press in the form.

**Update 1**
When I try calling `submitAjaxRequest()` I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`

**Update 2**
The Form Code that is generated is this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://dev.server.com/incidents" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="data-remote" id="incidentEntryForm"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="<TOKEN>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="city">Notrufort:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="city" type="text" id="city">
        </div>

        <!-- Latitude Form Input -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="street">Stra&szlig;e:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="street" type="text" id="street">
        </div>

        <!-- Notruftyp Form Input -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="type">Notruftyp:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="type" name="type"><option value="1">CPR</option></select>
        </div>

        <!-- Notruf erfassen Form Input -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" value="Notruf erfassen">
        </div>

        </form>
```

**Update 3**
I inserted a console.log at the beginning of the closure:

`var submitAjaxRequest = function(e) {
        console.log("submitAjaxRequest OK");(...)`

And the function is being called. The console prints the message. So I think something is wrong with the event.

**Update 4**
So I tried to use the pubSub System to listen to this event. Therefore I

```
function reverseGeoCode() {
    $.subscribe('form.submitted', function() {
        console.log("OK");
    })
}
```

But there is no reaction when I hit the submit button in the console. I used this function in a different script somewhere else on the page. Shouldn't it still react to the publish?

Comment: have you tried calling it like `submitAjaxRequest()`

Comment: Just tried. Now I get the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`

Comment: Can you post generated HTML?

Comment: Could it be that the event e in the closure is empty?

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/L4ab6e18/

Comment: I updated the post. Why does the function reverseGeoCode then not react to the published call? And why is the preventDefault error message there?

Comment: Might help if you put e.preventDefault() at end of ajax because is asynchronous the way it is now.

Comment: well the method submitAjaxRequest is only being called when I call it directly by submitAjaxRequest(). Why is the .on('submit') not working?

Comment: When I look at the logs in the console, only the PubSub Script and the AjaxHelper file in general are being loaded. but the submitAjaxRequest is not being called